# Quickbooks - 2500 error on active vendors

Tags: quickbooks, quickbooks-online

I currently have 50 vendor accounts setup to pay in QB Online, and about 15 of them return this 2600 error when creating a bill. Looking at the erorr documentation, it mentions the vendor is inactive, however i have assured they are active. All accounts are setup the same. I have queried the accounts using the api, and looked on QB for any differences, however they are all active, 1099, etc. What could be causing this issue? It seems the issue starts at Vendor Id=31. i.e. all vendors with id <=31 works, and all accounts > 31 return a 2500 error, however they are active!